# Snowflake CI CD using GITLAB yaml file

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, gitlab-ci

As part of a project, I need to setup snowflake CI CD using GITLAB and deploy my script to different environments, I have been able to get information about snowflake CI CD from GITHUB and Azure DEVOPS, but could not find any information about how to set up CI CD using GITLAB.

In order to deploy my script to different environments, I was expecting a yml file that can help me with Snowflake CI CD using GITLAB.

Comment: I don't see a question in your question, but if you are looking for tools to help, take a look at Permifrost: https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/business-technology/data-team/platform/permifrost/

Comment: I need a yml file to connet snowflake and gitlab so that I can deploy my script from Dev to Uat and Uat to mater.